# Java 8 stream from modified collection

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

Say I have a `List` of objects that being modified by only one thread (the thread can add or remove objects) and and another thread occasinally uses stream api from the above collecion to do some stream manipulation of it and at the end (eager operation) return a new collection. 
Is this a thread safe scenario? after all only one thread updates the collection.

Comment: I do not think so... what would happen should one thread remove an item while the other is attempting to read it? I might be wrong though, because I am unsure of how streams work under the hood.

Comment: It isn't a thread-safe scenario as you've got one thread writing and one or more threads reading. To make it thread safe you need to ensure that writes don't interfere with reads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This totally depends on your source `List` implementation. With [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#spliterator--) you *may* get [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) (or may get corrupted data or some other exception: see the comment). With [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#spliterator--) you can safely use stream operations: they will see the state of the list which was actual when the stream was created. In any case you should check the documentation for `spliterator()` method of the corresponding collection to see whether it's safe to use it in concurrent environment.

Comment: You *may* get a `ConcurrentModificationException` as it will be thrown an a *best-effort* basis. You *may* silently get corrupted data instead. Or a different exception which doesn’t tell you that it was caused by concurrent manipulation, e.g. an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You *may* get away with the broken code for a long time before spurious problems suddenly start occurring…

Answer (score 0):

You should get concurrent modification exception since your are reading and writing at the same time using this collection.

Comment: What if the collection allows concurrent modifications?